# if you want to create an object that holds arguments and parameters that represent a query string, what kind of object is best suited for this task?

Tags: java, dictionary, hashmap, query-string, hashtable

In .net there is a class named WebClient which has a property named "QueryString" which is of type NameValueCollection (a collection of key/value pairs where each key can have one or more values).

but since I'm working with java, and implementing a lot of functionality that's just not there by default, I was wondering what class I should use to create the object that is going to hold the key/value pairs that will be used to create the query string. Am I correct in assuming that java.util.Hashtable is the class that I want to use? Or is there a more appropriate alternative?

Comment: Spend some time reading Spring and Spring MVC documentation. It seems likely that Spring MVC will provide all the functionality you need.  Spring web site: http://www.springsource.org/

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I thought you were trying to encapsulate the request itself.

Ok, for the query, there are a ton of examples. Look at Hibernate or Hibernate Search. For sure, it's a good idea to have a real class and not just the HashMap. The class might have a map inside of the parameters, but the class could have a toString() that does the replacements, e.g. the HQL query string:

```
from Users where name = :name
```

when turned into a final string, would go into the map and find the entry who key is name (:name), pull it out and plug it into the query string.

Answer (score 0):

That depends what you're trying to do.

Personally, I don't think I've ever created such a class. When I want to put together a query string, I have a set of specific fields that I want to put in it, and I just use a StringBuilder or String "+" to put it together. That is, I don't have a Hashtable or any other sort of structure: I just have a handful of individual fields, whatever they might be. Normally I don't see what the value would be to putting the fields into a collection and then taking them back out.

That said, I'm sure there are cases where you have some generic function that you want to wrap around building a URL. In which case, sure a Hashtable -- or more likely a Hashmap, might as well use the newer collections -- would work fine.

Or, my first thought would be to create a new class to hold each parameter so it could have two distinct fields for name and value. Then you could put functions in the class to put them together with the equal sign between and do URL encoding. Then make an ArrayList of these objects. An ArrayList would be smaller and faster than a Hashtable, though on the scale of things any savings there is probably trivial.

But the point I started with is: What do you want to do with these parameters? If it's just: add parameters to the collection, then at some point pull them all out to build the query string, and that's all that ever happens, an ArrayList would be fine, a Hashtable would be fine, almost any collection would be fine.

Is there something else you want to do? Do you need to be able to retrieve elements from the collection at random? Merge two collections? Use the same class to hold parameters for some other purpose, e.g. a database query, so you can build the list and then pass it to either place? Etc etc.

What do you want to do if the caller tries to add two parameters with the same name. Should the second silently overwrite the first? Is that an error? Or what?

Etc.